# GetForegroundWindow() with Ticker C# - Reduce CPU Usage

Tags: c#, timer, monitor, cpu-usage, foreground

I am creating a program that will monitor computer usage. Part of this program requires that I know at all times what the foreground window is. That is achieved by this code:

```
    // Returns the name of the process owning the foreground window.
    private static Process GetForegroundProcess()
    {
        try
        {
            IntPtr hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
            // The foreground window can be NULL in certain circumstances, 
            // such as when a window is losing activation.
            uint pid;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);

            Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);

            return p;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The problem I am having is CPU consumption. This gradually uses all of my CPU because it is called within a ticker that ticks every second. Ticking every second is necessary for core functionality in the program.

My question then would be, is there a way to go about this without having my program freeze up the computer?

Thanks for your time and responses!

Comment: This doesn't make sense. A timer that ticked every second and then called that code would not use 100% CPU. Something else is wrong.

Comment: Are you calling `Dispose` on those `Process` objects after you're done with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the timer when you're code is running!. If its slower then the timer it'll lock up you're system.
Execute the code on a background thread and see if there is a different API to get the same information that works better.

Comment: The issue is I need the timer to be running at all times, so disabling it would be a problem. Also, I haven't found any other APIs that will do what I need unfortunately, but your information about it locking up the system if it's slower then the timer was good stuff, that slipped my mind.

Comment: You 'have' to 'disable' the timer when the code it runs is slower then the timer frequency. Just skip some of the slow update call if its still running.